# Can we run 2 server using openssl?

Tags: openssl, tls1.2

For openssl, I understand that we can run a client and a server separately.
The client would only need to verify the certificate chain of server.

Can I start 2 servers where each server verify the certificate chain of the others?

Comment: Please explain a bit more about what you're trying to do. This question lacks context and is not clear at all.

Comment: I am trying to set up 2 servers that can send certificate to each other using openssl

Comment: In TLS client's initiate connections. Servers receive connections. 2 server's cannot communicate with each other using TLS. There is always a client role and a server role. Why do you want 2 servers to talk to each other? You need to tell us what the end goal is.